# Adobe Acrobat submit form to webapi via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-web-api, adobe, acrobat

i am trying to submit a pdf using javascript using this approach.

```
var aSubmitFields = new Array( "BondSeriesProgram", "BondSeries" ); this.submitForm({cURL: "http://localhost:3030/api/loanstatus/submitpdf",aFields: aSubmitFields,  cSubmitAs: "HTML"});
```

this is doing the sumbit however it's sending the request payload like this
[image: Request Payload]

i am having a hard time accessing this data in the server, can someone guide me on how to do it. Thank you.

Comment: Your code looks correct. What type of fields are "BondSeriesProgram" and "BondSeries"?

Comment: they are strings

Comment: Can you share the PDF?

Comment: the pdf is being generated on the server using iTextSharp